# Focusing the next input after reaching the max length React Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to be able to move the focus from one input onto the next after the user has entered 2 numbers in the input box. Instead of the user manually clicking the next field I'd like the focus to switch there automatically.

Below is how I've currently implemented my two input fields.

I've tried the things mentioned here using refs but doesn't seem to work at all https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/react+native+textinput+focus

```
           <Controller
                control={form.control}
                defaultValue={initialMonthValue}
                name={monthName}
                render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) =>
                    <Input
                        containerStyle={{ width:80 }}
                        editable={!isSubmitting}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        numberOfLines={1}
                        multiline={false}
                        keyboardType='number-pad'
                        placeholder="MM"
                        maxLength={2} 
                        placeholderTextColor={Colors.Grey}
                        onChangeText={onChange}
                        onBlur={onBlur}
                        secureTextEntry={false}
                        invalid={!!monthError}
                        value={value} />}
            />
            <Slash text="/" />
            <Controller
                control={form.control}
                defaultValue={initialYearValue}
                name={yearName}
                render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) =>
                    <Input
                        containerStyle={{ width:80 }}
                        editable={!isSubmitting}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        numberOfLines={1}
                        multiline={false}
                        keyboardType='number-pad'
                        placeholder="YY"
                        placeholderTextColor={Colors.Grey}
                        onChangeText={onChange}
                        onBlur={onBlur}
                        secureTextEntry={false}
                        invalid={!!yearError}
                        value={value} />}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what are you looking to implement then this should work for you.

```
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function FormInputs() {

   const inputRef = useRef(null);
   const [length, setLength] = useState(0);

   const handleChange = (e) => {

     // Handle type checking here
   setLength(length + 1);
};

useEffect(() => {
  // if the Ref doesn't exist for some reason then break.
  if (!inputRef) return;

  const input = inputRef.current;

  if (length === 2) input.focus();
}, [length]);

  return (
    <>
      <input onChange={handleChange} />
      <input ref={inputRef} />
    </>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-platform-no55n?file=/src/App.js:77-590

if you would love me to help you implement this on your code then don't hesitate to share the components needed for the code to be functional.

Comment: Please consider taking the time to provide details about what you've changed/enhanced/provided in this solution. Explain why this works vs. what they tried.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm currently getting a Invariant Violation error seems to be an invalid hook call

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextInput`'s `focus` function. Here is a working example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [textInputValue1, setTextInputValue1] = React.useState('');

  const textInputRef2 = React.useRef<TextInput | null>();
  const [textInputValue2, setTextInputValue2] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        value={textInputValue1}
        onChangeText={(value) => {
          if (value.length >= 2) {
            textInputRef2.current?.focus(); // Focus on the other TextInput
          }
          setTextInputValue1(value);
        }}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        ref={(ref) => (textInputRef2.current = ref)}
        value={textInputValue2}
        onChangeText={(value) => setTextInputValue2(value)}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textInput: {
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
    margin: 20,
    minHeight: 40,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to get focus on the next input when I try the code above

Answer (score 0):

You can focus other Input's ref when you reach maxLength on first input' maxLength prop's value like this:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
const secondTextInputRef = useRef(null);

const [firstTextInputValue, setFirstTextInputValue] = 
React.useState('');
const [secondTextInputValue, setSecondTextInputValue] = 
React.useState('');

const maxInputSize = 3;

const App = () => {
     return (
       <View>
         <TextInput
            value={firstTextInputValue}
            maxLength={maxInputSize}
            onChangeText={(value) => {
                 setFirstTextInputValue(value);
                 if (value.length >= maxInputSize) {
                   secondTextInputRef.current?.focus();
               }
          }}/>
          <TextInput
             ref={(ref) => (secondTextInputRef.current = ref)}
             value={secondTextInputValue}
             onChangeText={(value) => setSecondTextInputValue(value)} />
        </View>
    );
};
export default App;
```